# Passing ravendb query as Func<T, bool> does not work

Tags: c#, ravendb

I'm playing with RavenDb and wondering if I'm missing something obvious.

Thing is, that if I'm passing query like this:

```
  var name = "test";
  posts = RavenSession.Query<Post>()
         .Where(x => x.Tags.Any(y => y == name))
         .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedAt)
         .Take(5);
```

It works ok, if i'm writing equivalent (IMO) using `Func<T, bool>`, it does not crash, but query is missing where condition:

```
 var name = "test";     
 Func<Post, bool> selector = x => x.Tags.Any(y => y == name);
 posts = RavenSession.Query<Post>()
         .Where(x => selector(x))
         .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedAt)
         .Take(5);
```

Profiler outputs it like:

> query=
>   start=0
>   pageSize=5
>   aggregation=None
>   sort=-CreatedAt

Update:
It works if I'm using expression instead of Func, so I thought may be I remember something wrong about Func and Linq, so wrote a simple test:

```
var range = Enumerable.Range(1, 50);

Func<int, bool> selector = x => x == 42;
var filtered = range.Where(x => selector(x));
```

So now it is only question why Raven Db query builder acts different.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using an `Expression` instead:

```
Expression<Func<Post, bool>> selector = x => x.Tags.Any(y => y == name);
```

And change `Where(x => selector(x))` to `Where(selector)`.

An `Expression` is required because RavenDb can build an expression tree from it, which allows it to translate the logic into database queries.  It cannot build an expression tree from a `Func<Post, bool>`, so it might either ignore it, throw an exeption or whatever the creators of RavenDb specified.

Comment: @Giedrius I added a short explanation to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

As a response to your update, there is significant behavioral differences between `Func<>` on `IEnumerable<>` and `Expression<Func<>>` on `IQueryable<>` that look syntactically identical. This is not just Raven, but any `IQueryable<>` source such as LINQ to SQL or Entity Framework.